# Run a Select command from a subreport in vba access

Tags: vba, ms-access, subreport

I want to run a select code from a table in Sub Report my code is:

```
Dim dbs As Database
  Set dbs = CurrentDb()
 Dim qdf As QueryDef
 Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs(Reports!Production![subreport dbo_Downsubreport7])
  qdf.SQL = "Select code from dbo_code"
```

I am getting error at line "Set qdf"

Comment: An error? There's lots of those. Which one are you getting?

Comment: Reports!Production![subreport dbo_Downsubreport7] is not a query

Comment: `dbs.QueryDefs()` is expecting the name of the query to be passed as string, e.g. `QueryDefs("QueryName")` See Sergey's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you have saved query with name `subreport dbo_Downsubreport7` (it should be visible in Navigation Pane), then use this syntax:

```
Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("subreport dbo_Downsubreport7")
```